# Apple Music "share song" not showing up when I have the same song on my local library on macOS Big Sur

Tags: music, apple-music, itunes-match

How can I share the link of a song to a friend when I have the exact same music (matched) in my library?

The "share to" button simple does not show up.

As an example:

[image: Apple Music share missing]

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Keep in mind a "matched" song can be a home demo or a commercially available song but either way, you aren't able to share those with other users. The workaround is to search for the identical song in Apple Music, i.e. not My Library, and share it from there.

Wish they would update the product to allow sharing of matched, commercially available songs but they haven't yet.

Comment: I've searched on Apple Music... when arriving at home I will edit the question with a better screenshot to better illustrate the issue.